# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver exception for connecting BigSQL using Python

Tags: apache-spark, db2, pyspark, bigsql

I'm new to pyspark.I'm using python 3.5 & spark2.2.0 on my Ubuntu 16.0. I wrote following code to connect BigSQL using pyspark

```python
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark_train_df = spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:db2://my bigsq url :port number:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=ibm-truststore.jks;sslTrustStorePassword=*password123;","schema.Table Name",
             properties={"user": username, 
                      "password": password,
                      'driver' : 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'}) # Trust store location is defined in .bashrc
spark_train_df.registerTempTable('data_table')

train_df = spark.sql('select * from data_table')
```

Also I have added my trust store & driver path in my .bashrc file
But while running this code I'm getting error message

```python
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver exception
```

Can you expert please guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to add these details (1) which Db2-client  name is installed (2) which is the version/fixpack of that Db2-client (3) Are you able to connect to the Db2 database from the bash command line or any other jdbc application running on ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much clue about DB2 Client. If you can kindly suggest me how to find those information then it will be helpful. As per as I know that latest DB2 client is being installed. Yes I'm able to connect BigSQL using python on Ubuntu

Comment: How do you execute the code? What's the command line for pyspark?

Comment: After writing the code in Jupyter note book I'm using jupyter's run command to execute the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the DB2 JDBC jars in your spark-submit, i.e., for postgres

```
spark-shell --master local[*] --packages  org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207.jre7
```

or (or DB2)

```
spark-shell --master local[*] --jars /path/to/db2/jdbc/db2.jar
```